# Winsock invalid received byte number

Tags: c++, c++11, winsock

I'm currently facing a `Winsock` related problem when trying to validate the number of received bytes.

In my application I'm using a non-blocking socket in order to throw my own `Timeout` exception. Here the according code for the initialization of `Winsock`:

```
// Initialize Winsock
WSAData winSockData;
WORD dllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
long iResult = WSAStartup(dllVersion, &winSockData);
if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
    return;

addrinfo* serverAddress = nullptr;
addrinfo* ptr = nullptr, hints;
ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "10011", &hints, &serverAddress);
if (iResult != 0)
    return;

// Create communication socket
SOCKET connectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, /*IPPROTO_TCP*/0);
if (connectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    return;

// Establish connection to server
iResult = connect(connectSocket, serverAddress->ai_addr, (int)serverAddress->ai_addrlen);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    return;

// Set socket to non-blocking
ULONG mode = 1;
m_iResult = ioctlsocket(m_connectSocket, FIONBIO, &mode);
if (m_iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    return;

// server address info not needed anymore
freeaddrinfo(serverAddress);
```

The application connects to a given telnet server first, sends a request and then awaits an according response message.

The incoming data gets stored in an appropriate char array, called `m_serverMsg` (with a fixed size of `BUFSIZE`, that is currently set at 4200 bytes).

If retrieving the server response message is taking to long (max. allowed time stored in `g_requestTimeout`), my own `TimeoutException` gets thrown.

Given server message has reached its end if a newline charachter (`\r\n`) has been found in the message buffer.

However, the following part for retrieving the server response message is not working as expected. Expected incoming data bytes are `1,040`, but actual bytes are always `3,435,973,836`.

```
unsigned long long startTime = getWallTimeInMs();
bool retry = true;
unsigned int receivedBytes = 0;
// Fetch server response
do
{

    try
    {

        m_iResult = fetchMessage(m_connectSocket, m_serverMsg, int(BUFSIZE - receivedBytes));
        if (m_iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            throw std::exception();

        if (m_iResult > 0)
        {
            for (unsigned int i = receivedBytes; i < receivedBytes + m_iResult; i++)
            {
                char* eol = strstr(m_serverMsg, "\r\n");
                if (eol)
                {
                    retry = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            receivedBytes += m_iResult;
        }
    }
    catch (CommException e)
    {
        // in case there's a short delay in retrieving the server response message
        if (getWallTimeInMs() - startTime < g_requestTimeout)
            Sleep(20);
        else
            // response timeout exceeded; connection has been lost
            throw CommException("server not responding in time.", CommProblem::ConnectionLost);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "There was a socket related problem." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Error code: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

} while (retry);
```

And this is how the function `fetchMessage()` looks like:

```
int CommCenter::fetchMessage(SOCKET socket, char* buffer, int bufSize, int flags)
{
    int result = recv(socket, buffer, bufSize, flags);
    // if operation couldn't be executed (e.g. because server is down),
    // throw according exception
    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
            throw CommException("delay in connection.", CommProblem::Delay);
        else throw;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Show ``fetchMessage``. You got  ``3,435,973,836`` in ``m_iResult ``? And when? ``break`` will stop only you ``for`` loop, not ``do-while`` loop.

Comment: Your error is inside fetchMessage. 3,435,973,836 is 0xcccccccc in HEX. This value is used by the compiler in debug mode to fill uninitialized variables. Show fetchMessage if you need help.

Comment: In Debug window it says for `m_serverMsg`: [content](http://jpst.it/ysW8)

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev `m_iResult` is a class member variable and gets assigned its value each time within the try{} block: `m_iResult = fetchMessage(...);`

Comment: `\r\n` is not a 'carriage return character', it is a CR/LF sequence of two bytes. NB There is no 'delay in connection' on EWOULDBLOCK, and associating it with 'connection lost' is also quite incorrect.

Comment: I think your program is way more complicated than necessary. I'd suggest using a timed wait operation on the socket via `WSAEventSelect` and related WinSock functions. That said, an actual minimal example would be a good thing, and crank up the warning level of your compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part

```
for (unsigned int i = receivedBytes; i < receivedBytes + m_iResult; i++)
{
    if (m_serverMsg[i] == '\r\n')
    {
        retry = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

is not correct, `'\r\n'` is not the same as `"\r\n"`, so you can not compare it like this.

To correct it use [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) function like this

```
char* eol = strstr(m_serverMsg, "\r\n");
if(eol != NULL)
{
    retry = false;
    break;
}
```

or convert `m_serverMsg` to `std::string` and use `find` method

```
if(std::string(m_serverMsg, receivedBytes, m_iResult).find("\r\n") != std::string::npos)
{
    retry = false;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Good to know, thx. But there's still the problem with the number of bytes received.

Comment: @neuronal.bit So ``3,435,973,836`` is the value of ``m_iResult`` after ``fetchMessage`` call?

Comment: That's correct. If `fetchMessage()` itself throws an exception, it gets caught before the number of received bytes can be assigned to `m_iResult`. Therefore `m_iResult` should always contain the number of actual received bytes, in case no error occurred.

Comment: @neuronal.bit Try to add debug output, for example ``printf("recv returned %d\n", result );`` in ``fetchMessage`` after ``recv`` call.

Comment: Interesting, within `fetchMessage()` the return value is `356`, but when assigned to `m_iResult` it is `3,435,973,836`! `m_iResult` is of type `int`.

Comment: Well, you need to do some debugging or add another debug output, to determine the real problem. At least add ``printf("fetchMessage returned %d\n", m_iResult);`` just after ``fetchMessage`` call. Also there is quiet a chance that the problem is in some part of your code you have not shown.

Comment: I tracked down the problem step by step and suddenly it works like a charm. Since your answer was the most meaningful, I accept it as the final answer.